# Loss of all git commits after changing the package name in Netbeans

Tags: java, github, netbeans, package

I have created classes in netbeans and they are all in the default package.

I wasn't able to rename the default package. So, I ended up creating a new one and moving the classes manually into the new package.

Once moved to the new package, the classes are losing all the history of the commits. Once pushed to git, the classes are showing inside a folder with the name of package and the classes that were in the default package are still there.

At this point, I can't delete the classes in the default package because they contain all the commits.

What is the procedure to rename the default package and keep the commits of the classes?

Screenshot of the error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

When you rename your package, the better option is `Refactor -> Rename` in NetBeans instead of manually renaming the package and moving each file. It will take care all the package to under it and java file to move and maintain the references.

You need to rename the repository, which you can found at [Github Help](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/). And, yes, you need to remap your repository details in NetBeans.

Comment: I cannot rename the package using refactor.

Comment: @LearnShareBuild what are you saying. I use to do everytime. And, this works in all IDE. What error are you getting ?

Comment: I am getting the error: The Rename refactoring cannot be applied in this context.

Comment: @LearnShareBuild Can you post the screenshot of how you are trying ?

Comment: @LearnShareBuild it's default package, there is no name for default package. It is not possible. And, my question, there is no Refactor option for default package for me, then how are you using it ?

Comment: I select the default package, choose Refactor from the top bar and then click rename. After that, I get the error shown above.

Comment: @LearnShareBuild No. You can't do that. Because, for me, it doesn't allow me to do.